# Can't set innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm not sure what the issue is here, but for some reason I am not able to get innerHTML to insert the string into my div on the 6th line of the below code. Here is the snippet:

```
var caption = $(this).attr('data-caption');
    if (caption) {
        //document.write(caption);
        $('.caption-overlay').addClass('show');
        $('.caption-overlay').removeClass('hide');
        $('.caption-overlay').innerHTML = caption;

    } else {
        $('.caption-overlay').addClass('hide');
        $('.caption-overlay').removeClass('show');
    }
```

I have checked over and over and `caption` is indeed returning a value, a simple text string.

The rest of the function is working fine and the if/else statement is firing correctly. I've tried for hours to figure out what's wrong...

I've also tried:

`$('.caption-overlay').innerHTML = caption.value;`

`$('.caption-overlay').innerHTML = String(caption);`

But neither of those is working either. Can anyone help?

Comment: `$('.caption-overlay')[0].innerHTML = caption;` for the first, or most likely `$('.caption-overlay').html(caption);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [jQuery.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
$('.caption-overlay').html(caption);
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, except without `value`. So `$('.caption-overlay').html(caption);`